# Does sendRedirect() happens at client side or at the server side?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, client-side, server-side, requestdispatcher

The theory says that 
***A request dispatch happens on the server, while a redirect happens on
 the client.***

Aren't that the both methods used in the servlet? Then both should happen at server side. Right? 

Or did i misunderstood what is client/server side? 
 Please give me clear explanation with some examples if you can. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect is a signal that server sends to the client with the means of HTTP response header.

HTTP `302` code is used along with a `location` header in the response from server. When client receives 302, it then uses URI specified by the Location header to fire a new request.

> A request dispatch happens on the server, while a redirect happens on
>   the client.

So redirection is initiated by the server but actual redirection happens on the client side, because client is responsible to send the new request.

Comment: Thank you. That is so clear, Will you little bit explain about HTTP 302 code if you don't mind.

Comment: yeah. sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

It works at client side because it uses the url bar of the browser to make another request. So, it can work inside and outside the server.

Comment: Thank u. thats simple. & can you explain me why requestDispatcher is being server side.

Comment: A RequestDispatcher object can forward a client's request to a resource or include the resource itself in the response back to the client. A resource can be another servlet, or an HTML file, or a JSP file, etc.

You can also think of a RequestDispatcher object as a wrapper for the resource located at a given path that is supplied as an argument to the getRequestDispatcher method.